# Housekeeping operations done in android

Tags: android

### USE-CASE:

***I am downloading songs from the server(internet). I am aware that song is first downloaded to RAM and then moved to flash-memory by android.***

---

*What happens in below scenarios:*

**`Scenario-1:`** Song is only `60%` downloaded to ram out of `100%`, and the user navigates into home screen by pressing `home button`- Will the remaining song be downloaded in background by android (should the programmer write a code to do it - or android does it automatically)

**`Scenario-2:`** Song is `100%` downloaded to ram by not yet moved to `flash`, programmer has written the code so that when the song is `100%` downloaded move it to flash. Now user presses the `home button`, now will the song be written to flash in background by android automatically ?

**`Scenario-3:`** Similar operations as `Scenario-1` & `Scenario-2` but this time user presses `switch-off button`. Now before the phone is turned off will the song be written from ram to flash (assuming the song is there in ram and had started writing to flash) before phone switches off or will it be interrupted

***Are there any android documentation or any online materials addressing above scenarios ?***

If anyone have additional scenarios...please edit my question and add those scenarios that i have missed !